# C# Math.Net - Polynomial Fit 3rd order produces unexpected equation?

Tags: c#, excel, polynomial-math, math.net

I have a graph with 4 points:

{0.0, 0.0},
{4687500.0, 10647580.9},
{4687500.1, 10647580.9},
{7500000.0, 10213609.9},

Using these points, in Excel I plot a 3rd order polynomial fit, which gives me the equation:

y = -4E-14x3 + 2E-07x2 + 1.5x + 2E+06

Which is **perfect**, and exactly what I need to draw the curve I'm after (the curve Excel draws is spot on).

However when I use the C# Math.Net library to plot a 3rd order polynomial fit using the exact same 4 points, I get a completely different set of coefficients (and therefore a hugely different equation and graph).

```
var coefficients = MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Polynomial(budgets, profits, 3);
```

Any ideas why this is the case? The coefficients match perfectly when I use 2nd order, so I'm wondering if there's something special about the Math.Net 3rd order function.

The Excel curve rises, and later dips (what I'm after).

The Math.NET curve rises, dips, and then rises again towards the end.

EDIT: We are using 3rd order rather than 2nd order, because we need to keep 10647580.9 as the highest Y point when the curve is drawn.

Comment: *"Which is perfect, and exactly what I need to draw the curve I'm after (the curve Excel draws is spot on).*". You hace a 2 million error at `X = 0.0` so I'm not quite sure what *spot on* means for you.

Comment: And why are you even using a 3rd order fit at all? Your example is a 2nd order curve.

Comment: The Excel curve is appropriate for the case. The problem with 2nd order is this will draw points higher than the highest point ({4687500.0, 10647580.9}), using 3rd order in Excel forces this input value to be maintained as the highest point, which is what is needed in this case.

Comment: That is completely data dependant. A third degree order fit doesn't guarantee that at all. Its just the case that in *this* particular set of points it happens to be so.

Comment: Can you produce a case of 4 points which doesn't suit this approach in Excel? (bare in mind we're forcing the .1 at the 3rd point to create the necessary shape)

Comment: Of course, thousands. `(0, 0), (1, 1), (5, 10), (10, 0)` will give you a perfect fit. The maximum value of the 3rd order fit is close to `12` at aproximately `X = 6.5`.

Comment: If there's a more appropriate way of using 2nd order, and ensuring the curve doesn't go higher than the max input point - that would be very useful.

Comment: Its hard to figure out what you are doing, but, no, neither Excel nor `Numerics` will give you the best fit constrained to a maximum value.

Comment: In simple terms we can plot up to 10 points on the graph, so ideally we'd look to get a best fit for those. The problem is the curve peak absolutely cannot exceed the highest point (accuracy doesn't matter so much the further you move away from that point). But if this isn't possible, we might need to go with a staggered curve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136972/discussion-between-inbetween-and-fbryant87).

Comment: If the example data you show is typical, you're likely to run into roundoff minefields. The 2nd and 3rd points are, for practical purposes, identical. In practice this means you *really* have 3 data points not 4. Fitting a cubic polynomial to such data will give nearly meaningless results.

Answer (score 2):

A comment for anyone who stumbles on this much later. This computation is at the limit of precision for either Excel or Numerics which is about 15 digits. A bit of imprecision results. When I reproduced the computation exactly in Math.Net, it ran okay, but when I divided all the numbers by 1,000, it crashed with a "Matrix must be positive definite" error.

Another example:

```
x = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
            y = new double[] { 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0 };
            rslt = MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Polynomial(x, y, 3, DirectRegressionMethod.QR);
            Console.WriteLine("Test - QR");
            for (int i = 0; i < rslt.Length; i++) Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "  " + rslt[i].ToString());
```

returned

```
0  10
1  0.999999999999994
2  1.18687833744435E-15
3  0
```

I doubt that fitting a polynomial was the best solution for the OP. They are not as flexible as one might hope.